# WebBrowser textbox is not accepting when clicking on date from Datepicker

Tags: c#, browser

I have a `WebBrowser` in my win application and it needs to read some data from `php` web site. When I click on Date Textbox that has a Datepicker and pick a date it doesn't show on textbox. But when I open the same page on `Internet Explorer` and pick some date it works well.

What can be the issue with my `WebBrowser`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION in registry so that WebBrowser can behave same as your internet explorer.

From this [post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version)

The key to write to is:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

Value Key: DWORD  YourApplication.exe
```

Note that the FeatureControl and FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION keys may not exist at all prior to installation, so you may have to install that whole branch.
For all Users:

There are two different sets of keys for 32 bit and 64 bit applications.

```
64 bit or 32 bit only machine: 

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

Value Key: DWORD - YourApplication.exe

32 bit on 64 bit machine: 

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

Value Key: DWORD YourApplication.exe
```

The value to set this key to is (taken from MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation)) as decimal values:regi

**11001 (0x2EDF)**
Internet Explorer 11. Webpages are displayed in IE11 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.

**11000 (0x2AF8)**
Internet Explorer 11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.

**10001 (0x2AF7)**
Internet Explorer 10. Webpages are displayed in IE10 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.

**10000 (0x2710)**
Internet Explorer 10. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.

**9999 (0x270F)**
Internet Explorer 9. Webpages are displayed in IE9 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.

**9000 (0x2328)**
Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.

**8888 (0x22B8)**
Webpages are displayed in IE8 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.

**8000 (0x1F40)**
Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode.

**7000 (0x1B58)**
Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode.

EDIT 1:

You can use your product installer to create this entry in the registry.

Comment: I am also trying to use `GeckoWebBrowser` instead of WebBrowser. But it doesn't show up anyting on startup. What could be the cause?

Comment: Have you tried the solution I posted for WebBrowser?

Comment: Yes it works in my PC, but I have about 20-30 users and they all have different PC's with different specs. That's why I am trying to use `GeckoWebBrowser` instead.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. Don't go for GeckoWebBrowser, I have also faced the same situation and we have thousands of users all around the world. So I have given this responsibility to my installer for creating the entry in the registry. Hope you can also do the same.

Comment: How can I include in my Installer to create this entry automatically on any machine (32 or 64 bit)

Comment: That depends on the installer you are using, If you are using default msi installer then it has build in Registry Editor where you can add the entry as per your requirement. Otherwise you can start  some other thread to get the help on the type of installer you are using. Please don't forget to mark as answer to the replies that helped you.